# Popen command fails with returncode 1

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

Strangely when django invokes the below code `Popen` returns `returncode=1` with empty `err`. But when I run this program manually it works fine. I don't have any idea how to debug as `err` is empty. This is my code (docsplit converting pptx to pdf):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def execute_commands(commands):
    for command in commands:
        # I know the consequences of shell=True
        process = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        try:
            out, err = process.communicate()
            errcode = process.returncode
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            process.terminate()
            process.wait()
            raise

        if errcode != 0:
            raise Exception('ErrorCode %s: %s' % (str(errcode), err))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commands = ["/usr/bin/docsplit pdf --output %s %s" % ('test.pdf', 'test.pptx')]
    execute_commands(commands)
```

My Environment is:

- Python 2.7.3
- Django 1.4.4
- Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

The command "works fine" from the command line, but have you actually checked that it is returning success?  It might not.  What does `echo $?` say after you execute it by hand?